# SDL can't find my main function

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

I set up my application with the SDL Framework and it works without any error.
But when I try to start my program it terminates immediately, even before entering my simple main method. Here the code:

```
#include "CApp.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello";  
    return 0;
}
```

I know that SDL implements its own main function in SDLMain.m and starts manually my main function. I think that I found the code in STLMain.m that executes my main function (line 222ff):

```
/* Create SDLMain and make it the app delegate */
sdlMain = [[SDLMain alloc] init];
[NSApp setDelegate:sdlMain];

/* Start the main event loop */
[NSApp run];
```

When I set a breakpoint on `[NSApp run]` and make a step forward the program terminates.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Apart from that, no, SDL doesn't call `main()`. It is called by the OS on app startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL `#define`s `main` to `SDL_main` in order to transparently use its own `main` implementation. Since you haven’t included any SDL headers, you don’t have that macro in scope. It should work to simply rename your `main` to `SDL_main` or include an SDL header such as `SDL.h`.

Comment: `SDL.h` is in `CApp.h`included. I solved the problem now after I added the original `SDLMain` files again. Seems I did something there I shouldn't do.